# Comparison String to String

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I got these 2 examples below -

`console.log("a" > "3")` // outputs true

`console.log("hello" > "3")` // outputs true

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than), `If both values are strings, they are compared as strings, based on the values of the Unicode code points they contain`.

But then they also wrote the following in the next paragraph, `Strings are converted based on the values they contain, and are converted as NaN if they do not contain numeric values.`

Following this logic, shouldn't both statements be `false` since no matter what the operator it is, "a" and "hello" are words in strings and they don't have a numerical value, therefore, it should return `NaN`, and `NaN` is false; hence, as soon as one of the operands is `false`, it outputs `false`?

If I need to adhere to the former statement above, could you please walk me through this logic?

Thanks.

Comment: I am new to JS, and super meticulous about details, so please don't judge me too harshly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing two strings (in quotation marks), not a string to a number. This should answer your question:

```
"a" > "3" //true
"a" > 3 //false
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand the second ex. you provided here. I am asking how exactly does the comparison happen for `"a" > "3"`

Comment: It compares the unicodes for the strings, character by character, starting at the first one. "a" is 61 in unicode, while "3" is 33. 61 > 33 so it returns true.

Comment: could you please send me the unicode documentation you are referencing?

Comment: Tbh I'm not sure if my 2nd comment was accurate (just googled a random unicode table, not 100% sure if it uses EXACTLY that) but in pretty much every standard, alphabetical characters are assigned a higher code than numerical characters anyway. For example you can also try the JS internal function "a".charCodeAt(0) //97 vs "3".charCodeAt(0) //51. Still 97 > 51.

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase from the MDN article is

> If both values are strings, […].
> **Otherwise** JavaScript attempts to convert non-numeric types to numeric values

So no, `"a"`, `"3"` and `"hello"` are all strings, and when comparing them, they get compared as strings. No conversion to anything occurs.

Comment: So how does the comparison exactly happen here?

Comment: They are referencing the Unicode code points, but how do I apply it here? I can't to find any proper/reliable documentation about it anywhere

Comment: Basic characters from Unicode are identical with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set)

Answer (score 0):

As you've written,

> If both values are strings, they are compared as strings, based on the
> values of the Unicode code points they contain

So, on both examples, both values are strings. If you change "3" to 3, the result is:

```
console.log("a" > 3)
// expected output: false

console.log("hello" > 3)
// expected output: false
```

That's because, first it's converted as NaN, and then:

> If either value is NaN, the operator returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The docs:

> If both values are strings, they are compared as strings, based on the values of the Unicode code points they contain.

> **Otherwise** JavaScript attempts to convert non-numeric types to numeric values: ....

Reading the docs, I understand that, if BOTH strings have numerical values (both not NaN), then both are treated as Unicode code points. Otherwise, if BOTH have numerical values, then they're converted.

But anyways, my sugestion for a js beginer: do not get too attached to how the language works for now, and even tho it **can** compare strings with "greater" and "less than", I dont think there would (or should) be a real life scenario where you would need it.

Also, just for fun, check [this pen](https://codepen.io/diguifi/pen/NJgveY) I made when I first started with js (I was also very confused about comparison and typing xD):

```
"" == null // this one is fun
```

Later, after learning more about the language, you'll get why somethings work like they do in js, I also recomending understanding the history of js and the web, it explains a lot of the weird behaviours of the language.

Comment: How is `==` relevant here?

Comment: As stated "Also, just for fun...". It's not relevant for the question, but it's a weird/fun behaviour to explore when you're new to js.

Comment: Okay, though `==` is not related to order relation, i.e. `a == b` is not the same as `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`; `a === b` is also not the same; these have very different semantics. Some of these operators coerce their arguments, as specified in the runtime semantics of the specification (e.g. for [`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), and for [`==`, `!=`, `===`, `!==`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation)).

Comment: I agree. But I think you've also missed " I made when I **first started with js** (I was also very confused about comparison and typing xD)". Now I know the differences and why things work the way they do. But it doesn't change the fact that, for a beginner, it looks and feels bizarre. And since the guy questioning is himself a beginner, I thought it would be fun to share my own experience as such.